# TYPO3 - typoscript - sys_category

Tags: typo3, categories, typoscript, sys

I'm trying to display the title of the `sys_category` of a given content-element in a list-view, here a sysfile, but i can't get the single cat for each element, what I'm doing wrong? I know, this question has been asked before, but there is no fitting answer yet. No fluid, please TS ;)

```
lib.category = COA
lib.category {
10 = CONTENT
  10 {
    table = sys_category
    select {
      pidInList = 1
      join = sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = sys_category.uid
      # static id works
      #where = (uid_foreign = 751) 
      # here is the mistake?
      where.data = (uid_foreign = uid)  
      selectFields = title
    }

    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj.field = title
    renderObj.wrap = Kategorie:|

    stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = TEXT
    stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject.value = no-cat
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The following information is needed: How to you get the content elements.

Comment: the elements come from a file collection

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have everything in your current record in cObject->data available, you can access it like this:

```
lib.category = COA
lib.category {
  10 = CONTENT
  10 {
    table = sys_category
    select {
      pidInList = 1
      join = sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = sys_category.uid
      where.data = field:uid
      where.intval = 1
      where.wrap = (uid_foreign = |)  
      selectFields = title
    }

    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj.field = title
    renderObj.noTrimWrap = |Category: ||

    stdWrap.ifEmpty = no-cat
  }
}
```

I also simplified and optimized the rendering of the category and ifEmpty rendering.

Please note that this only works to get categories of ONE content element.

Comment: it seems that cObject->data has only the number of categories available, was that what you meant ? in any case I cannot get this to work, would it be different in V10 ?